# canot find mongodb error but VS shows it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, visual-studio, module, typescript

I am developing Node.JS app in Visual Studio (2015) with Node.JS tools and I installed NPM package mongodb. But when I want to require mongodb module, it fails with error

> Cannot find module 'mongodb'

In solution explorer > project > npm is this package shown´. Why it throws error? TypeScript Code for loading module is

```
import mongo = require('mongodb');
// converted to JS
var mongo = require('mongodb');
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "XYZ",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "_XYZ",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "zurmi",
    "email": "fsdgsdfgsdf@sadfasdf.sd"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "2.0.47"
  }
}
```

[image: Solution explorer shows mongodb package]

Comment: One possible solution to your problem has been discussed in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226410/node-js-cannot-find-module-mongodb)

Comment: I have read it. It is not working. When I install package globaly, it does not work too.