# Strider "npm start" generating errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install a Strider instance on an AWS EC2 instance. I have installed all the perquisites as described in [this document](https://futurestud.io/blog/strider-how-to-install-the-platform-and-plugins) but have run across a problem running Strider using `npm start`.

I have confirmed that MongoDB is running correctly.

I will eventually run it as a service, but I'd like to check it's running first. I receive pages of errors along the lines of:

> strider@1.8.0 start /home/ubuntu/strider
>   bin/strider

```
6800 forked
module.js:341
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '../../../models'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/strider/lib/routes/collaborators/api.js:3:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/strider/lib/routes/collaborators/index.js:9:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/strider/lib/app.js:44:27)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/strider/main.js:9:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
6800 died 1 null
```

I have looked at [this overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226410/node-js-cannot-find-module-mongodb) but it doesn't solve my problem unfortunately. I do not appear to have a `server.js` anywhere.

Is there some configuration I need to do?

Comment: Run this command on your EC2 instance nano ~/.bashrc and paste this line in that file export NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/node_modules" and then try to run.

Comment: But there isn't a /usr/lib/node_modules folder.

Comment: Does this path exists /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Comment: Nope, it doens't. /usr/local/lib exists. Does this indicate an error in node installation?

Comment: What is the output of node -v

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118743/discussion-between-error2007s-and-serlingpa).