# Where should I install Mongodb to work with nodejs in localhost?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I installed mongodb in C:\Program Files and I can run it in the terminal but I don't know how to make the connection to the localhost so that I can connect to it using node. This is the link that I've found for connecting to Mongodb:

[Best way to connect to MongoDB using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485575/best-way-to-connect-to-mongodb-using-node-js)

I get Mongoclient not defined and "cannot find module mongodb".

I followed tutorials on how to install Mongodb and that's why it's installed in Program files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js cannot find module 'mongodb'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226410/node-js-cannot-find-module-mongodb). Note that you appear to be confusing the database itself from the driver package used by the application (having the former installed but not the latter)

Comment: I checked the answers and it didn't solve the problem.